# Whiskers instead of bars in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

For a given bar plot, like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y_bot = np.linspace(30, 50, 10)
y_dif = np.linspace(10, 5, 10)

plt.bar(x, y_dif, bottom=y_bot)
```

[image]

I would like to have whiskers (like in a boxplot), instead of bars:

[image]

How can I edit the bars to appear as whiskers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`plt.errorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/stats/errorbar_plot.html#sphx-glr-plot-types-stats-errorbar-plot-py) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y_bot = np.linspace(30, 50, 10)
y_dif = np.linspace(10, 5, 10)

plt.bar(x, y_dif, bottom=y_bot, color='skyblue')
plt.errorbar(x, y_bot, yerr=(np.zeros_like(y_bot), y_dif), capsize=10, ecolor='black', ls='', lw=5, capthick=5)

plt.gca().use_sticky_edges = False # remove stickyness due to plt.bar()
plt.xticks(x)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.errorbars instead of bars]